# How send .zip file to Facebook App review

Tags: facebook

I tried to send .zip file to Facebook app review but my simulator build file is more than 100Mo. So Facebook ask URL for files more than 100 Mo, i tried to share my file with Wetransfer or Google drive but Facebook doesn't download file from this platform. DO you have any solution to send my file to Facebook app review ?

Comment: I would try zipping it with RAR, BZIP and 7-Zip as this can sometimes provide better compression ratios with some data.

Comment: I tried but file stay more than 100Mo